# Django ORM and dependencies

Tags: django, orm, python-2.7, model

I am currently brainstorming about building an existing PHP CodeIgniter project in Django.
I spit through the documentation a bit already and done some online tutorials to test how it works and am really charmed by it.

The theoretical design issue I'm currently facing is that in what I have in mind; ***Apps*** will be dependent on each other, yet the Django documentation itself states that it ***Apps*** should be *pluggable*.

The thing is that I have a ***Products*** App with different sub-properties like colors, groups, models (foreign key relationships). Now I started thinking on how to use my ***Invoices*** App, but I instantly notice that the ***Invoices*** App will need products from the ***Products*** App.

I wonder how other people do this in their Django projects? Would I need to rethink the way I design my whole application (Products, Invoices, Orders, Deliveries, Email, etc.) and how they are linked individually?

Would I tell Django that my ***Invoices*** App *needs* my ***Products*** App to be initialized , or do I totally remodel the situation having something like an ***ERP*** App that house all those parts as their own *Models*?

---

In the end I want to have my front-office to also be converted to Django (Webshop) and access my back-office (ERP) products. I also wonder how I would incorporate that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are asking, but here are some tips, based on some hard-learned lessons.

1. Apps should do *one* thing, and one thing only. If you can't describe what your app does without three or four "ands" in the sentence, you need to rethink your app.
2. Models are tied to apps; but this doesn't mean you can't use models from app A, in app B. A model by itself is not an app; you can't say *"Products app with different sub-properties"*.
3. You can have apps that have models but no views if that's what's required. There is no requirement that an app must serve a view.
4. Keep your views simple, your models rich, and for your application you'll probably have lots of utility scripts that serve as helpers, this is fine and encouraged.  You don't want lots of complicated logic in your views, and you *really* don't want lots of logic in your templates.

When the django documentation states that apps are pluggable, what it means is that application should be standalone; all their required dependencies (templates, urls, views, models) should be encompassed together with the app such that you can publish it and people can download and integrate your app with minimal impact. The release of 1.5 brought a new section in the tutorial [how to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/reusable-apps/) which should provide more insight.

I would argue that a good pluggable app is one that can easily be 'chained together' to solve a problem.

Comment: One important design detail is that applications cannot have circular dependencies. You might end up tying yourself when your designing the relationships and modularizing them into apps and the models layer often ends up being quirky because of design issues.

Comment: Good point Filip but from what I have seen, that trap comes when people design the tables, then try to map the app to the tables; instead of designing the logic and use case first, thinking in terms of objects; and letting the ORM sort out the tables. The biggest challenge would be to understand the philosophy behind the framework and not try to write whatever you know into django (like trying to write RoR in django or PHP in django). It can be done, but you'll end up with problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom. I'm currently still reading a lot of the documentation and the new tutorial you've linked. I'm just very curious about the structure on how I would intelligently structure my "ERP" website. My Products would contain a lot of Variants of Colors and Models. Those Products will be placed on Offers, that can be transformed to Orders. Those orders can be fully or partially delivered. After those are finished by sending an Invoice (or Credit Invoice). My CodeIgniter structure is pretty clear, but DataMapper and all the *teamwork* made it one big soup due the different styles.

Comment: The major problem our project has is that the strong relationships and how they are intertwined within the whole system makes the system's code hard to read. Django really looks like something that would aim the whole team to work toward neater and unified code (as PHP is pretty loose). Also the ORM mechanics look way more readable and charming than what we use in basic CodeIgniter and DataMapper.

Comment: Keep in the mind the best framework won't help if your models aren't designed correctly. So before diving into that part, considering the structure of your models and relations (not your tables, but your models). Also keep in mind that modeling "multi variance" products in a relational database has its problems. You might consider a hybrid solution where variations and product details are stored in a document database, and only transactional information is stored in a relational database (where transactional integrity and rollbacks are necessary).

Comment: Agreed, there are more data structure options to examine to find a fit for your problem domain. There are excellent packages that integrate non-relational databases with Django and you can always resort to plain Python within the confines of Django's APIs.